# Sort Dictionary by Values

Tags: python, linux

I have a dictionary of ints.

```
d = {'jjd':2,'ddf':1,'kik':3}
```

Its much longer then this though. I want to sort by values highest to lowest. But I really want the results returned in an array so I can iterate through it like so:

```
for x in results:
    print d[x]
```

this should print out:
    ['kik','jjd','ddf']

Comment: see post: https://www.pythoncentral.io/how-to-sort-python-dictionaries-by-key-or-value/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following collect the keys of the dicts items, sorted by descending value:

```
results = [k for k, v in sorted(d.items(), key=lambda i: i[1], reverse=True)]
# ['kik', 'jjd', 'ddf']
```